# How to get the php values of a row on a table in jQuery when clicking on that row?

Tags: php, html, jquery, href

I have a table with dynamic data from the db, which currently I populate using PHP and I am using `href` to navigate when clicking on those values, however, I would like to make the entire row clickable instead of just the text on it.

This is one column how it looks like:

```
  <td>
      <?php echo '<a href=closed_rma_selected.php?rep_id=' . urlencode($user["id"]) . "&cus_id=" . urlencode($user["cus_id"]) . "&name=" . urlencode($user["name"]) . '>' . $user["id"] . '</a>'; ?>
  </td>
```

Comment: give some padding to your anchor

Comment: @RamondeVries I dont understand what you mean

Comment: `<a style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;" href=closed_rma_selected.php?rep_id=' . urlencode($user["id"]) . "&cus_id=" . urlencode($user["cus_id"]) . "&name=" . urlencode($user["name"]) . '>' . $user["id"] . '</a>` < try this. let me know what happens

Comment: @RamondeVries I would like to know what do you want me to achieve with padding?! I am trying to make rows clickable, what does padding has to do with that?

Comment: `I would like to make the entire row clickable instead of just the text on it.` according to this. i believe that making the anchor as wide and high as whatever its inside will fix your problem

Comment: @RamondeVries tried it, nothing changed, still only the text is clickable.

Comment: @RamondeVries, he means the entire `<tr>` not the entire `<td>`

Comment: Please clarify - do you want to "get the php values" (question title) or do you want to "click" on the anchor (question text) - these are very different issues.

Comment: @freedomn-m actually both because I dont want to just click on a row but of course I need to take those values when clicking.

Comment: But when you click on the `<a>` it will "take" those values to the next page - is that what you mean?  Otherwise they contradict as you take the values (into local variables) then navigate to next page and the local variables are lost - so if you're navigating via `<a>` you don't need to "take" (retrieve) the values first.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the current html spec doesn't allow interactive elements (like `<a>` anchors) to encapsulate table rows. And likely will never support it (due to inherit differnece in rendering between cell structures and inline/block type elements)

you can however use `Jquery` to do this.

You can acomplish it with the following code:

> Replace values in `{name}` with your unique values

```js
    $('#{your tables id}').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var destination = currentElement.find(".{classNameOfAnchor}").eq(0).attr('href');
        window.location = destination;
    });
```

A codepen for demo purposes:
https://codepen.io/yourikoeman/pen/rNxNdJY

Comment: "Replace values in {name} with your unique values" ? Where is that {name} ?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding i mean every value within `{` and `}` i just named them so you know what is suppossed to go there

Comment: since you said you dynamically load the rows i added the listener to the table itself, but if you load the entire table dynamically this will not work, you need to add the listener on a element that is already in the dom opun startup of the page

Comment: ok, how is it possible to get the php values in this code? I dont see it anywhere being done

Comment: Those should alrady be in the dom right? how would you otherwise click on them?

Comment: I just tried  `$('#myTable tr').on('click', function() {
            var currentElement = $(this);
            var destination = currentElement.find(".ClientHref")[0].attr('href');
            window.location = destination;
        });` but doesn't make any difference

Comment: `.find(".ClientHref")[0].attr` will give an error - use `.eq(0)` instead of `[0]`

Comment: oops my bad, i wrote this blind inside the markdown editor of stackoverflow :/

Comment: "*how is it possible to get the php values*" - nowhere (other than the apparently unrelated title to the question text) have you asked to "get php values" - you've asked how to activate an `<a>` click when clicking on a `<tr>`.  Asked for clarification in question comments.

Comment: could you please clarify what you want better first? the clickable part i can guide you with with the information provided, but what do you want with the php values?

Comment: @YouriKoeman I just want to make the rows clickable and when clicking on them I want to take all the respective values of each row (which I am displaying using PHP) and navigate to another page where I can use `$_GET[]` to get those values from the url.

Comment: @YouriKoeman sorry for the late reply. I tried it but still nothing, if I click on a row it doesn't re direct me anywhere.

Comment: what does your developer console say?